# count pattern occurrences using shell

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a generated trace and want to do some simple analysis based on the shell command `awk` and `sed`. The format of the trace is:

```
../filter_on/2016-01-11--22.24.30/ruby/observ/out/observ_jruby_optimalj9_OUT:11/Jan/2016:22:50:03:941  java.lang.invoke.ReceiverBoundHandle  MethodHandle(ThreadContext)IRubyObject
../filter_on/2016-01-11--22.24.30/ruby/printff/out/printff_jruby_optimalj9_OUT:11/Jan/2016:22:29:30:585  java.lang.invoke.ReceiverBoundHandle  null
../filter_on/2016-01-11--22.24.30/ruby/printff/out/printff_jruby_optimalj9_OUT:11/Jan/2016:22:29:30:586  java.lang.invoke.PermuteHandle  null
../filter_on/2016-01-11--22.24.30/ruby/cal/out/cal_jruby_optimalj9_OUT:11/Jan/2016:22:54:17:683  java.lang.invoke.ReceiverBoundHandle  null
../filter_on/2016-01-11--22.24.30/ruby/cal/out/cal_jruby_optimalj9_OUT:11/Jan/2016:22:54:17:684  java.lang.invoke.ReceiverBoundHandle  null
```

and my expected output is table:

```
observ   ReceiverBoundHandle  MethodHandle(ThreadContext)IRubyObject   1
printff  PermuteHandle        null             1
printff  ReceiverBoundHandle  null    1  
cal      ReceiverBoundHandle  null    2
```

The last column is the times that first three columns are seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `awk`, `sort`, and `uniq`. If you can live with this and the counter of repeats being the first rather than the last column, then this should do:

```
cat trace | awk -F "[/ ]+" '{print $5"\t"$10"\t"$11}' | sort | uniq -c
```

The output on a file with your input is like:

```
  2 cal     java.lang.invoke.ReceiverBoundHandle    null
  1 observ  java.lang.invoke.ReceiverBoundHandle    MethodHandle(ThreadContext)IRubyObject
  1 printff java.lang.invoke.PermuteHandle  null
  1 printff java.lang.invoke.ReceiverBoundHandle    null
```